# Practical staging of config

Tags: drush, 8, configuration

I am successfully migrating at least the bulk of my config from `dev` thru `stage` to `prod`. But the process could obviously be more robust.

Current procedure:

- create central (bare) repository
- create `dev`

  - clone to `dev` machine
  - perform set-up (usually `standard` template) using separate `sites/dev.mysite.com` settings. No content. No real settings beyond the defaults imported from the template and the `install.php` process.
  - export config to `from_dev` config dir
  - push all to central repository.
- create `stage`

  - clone to `stage`
  - perform identical setup but using `sites/stage.mysite.com` instead.
  - import config from the `from_dev` config dir

    - use `drush config-edit` to change the freshly created UUID's for `system.site` and `shortcut.set.default` so they match the UUID's from the `dev` site.
    - use `drush config-import` to duplicate the config from `dev`.

Basically repeat this process for any other sites in the staging tree.

Problems:

- All the sites now have identical UUID.

  I'm not clear on the value/purpose of UUID but as long as they are all unique within a site; I'm not sure that's a problem?
- The import process does not have the ability to modify existing config objects when the change is limited to UUID. If the UUID's differ, the old object is deleted and the new (otherwise identical object) is created from scratch. This has the side effect of also deleting any content associated with the old object.

  In theory, this sort of delete/replace only happens during initial setup before the sites have any data; so there's no harm. However, great care is obviously required to guarantee that no "important" object will be deleted thru the entire life of the project.

Is this an intended D8 workflow?

Should the UUID (either in the live target `stage` site or in the configs from `dev` to be imported) be edited to match before the import?

Is there anyway to instantiate a D8 `stage` (`prod`) site that is genuinely "blank" (i.e.: an initial config import would require no editing of UUID and/or deletion/recreation of config objects)?

I've been using the `standard` template because it includes things like `Configuration Manager` which facilitate the config sharing process. Note that if `stage` is not built with the same template as `dev` than the import will fail with something like (paraphrase from memory): `Unable to uninstall module 'minimal' because it does not exist; Unable to install module 'standard' because it does not exist.` Is there a better template for this process?

Comment: I think this question can use some editing, but we will be needing a canonical question/answer about CM in Drupal 8.

Comment: Please feel free to edit as it makes sense to you. As I wrote it, the question is rambling; but I'm struggling to come up with a coherent question to a real problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it this way:

Have a branch master:

Create 2 separate branches fed from the master (master being prod):
- stage
- test

Create a new branch abcfeature based from master, after complete, merge to stage/test.

Use domain alias's to setup different URLS in your test environment.